# Nested Parse queries don't return the correct result

Tags: php, parse-platform

I'm trying to retrieve a list of posts from following users with Parse. Here is how I'm trying to achieve that.

First of all, I get the list of people followed by the current user :

```
// Fetch Following People
$fetch_following_query = new Parse\ParseQuery("Follower"); 
$fetch_following_query->equalTo("from", $user);
```

This query works because it returns one entry, which is good.

Then, I want to list all of the posts written by the people the current user is following :

```
// Fetch Posts
$fetch_posts_query = new Parse\ParseQuery("Post");
$posts_results = null;

// Show only approved posts from people I follow
$fetch_posts_query->descending("createdAt");
$fetch_posts_query->includeKey("author");
$fetch_posts_query->matchesKeyInQuery("author", "from", $fetch_following_query);
$fetch_posts_query->limit(3);
```

I have one post written by the user I'm actually following but this last nested query doesn't return anything, which is obviously not what I want.

About the Parse classes :

- I have one "Follower" class with two pointers "from" and "to" to the User class. So I know who is following who.
- I have one "Post" class which contains the informations about the posts (content, date, author...) with one "author" pointer to the User class.

Can you see something wrong with my queries ?

Thanks!

Comment: should it be `"author", "to"`, otherwise you're checking for posts the user wrote themselves ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you just need to change your `matchesKeyInQuery` to have parameters `"author", "to"`, otherwise you're checking for posts the user wrote themselves.